# Cannot setup Ambari server with MySQL

Tags: mysql, hadoop

I was playing around with Ambari server. I followed the manual and did everything as it says. When I tried to do the "ambari-server setup", I entered "advanced database configuration" because I wanted to use MySQL instead of PostgreSQL. The manual says there should be several options, and MySQL should be optino 3. But all I could see was two options, and MySQL is not in there. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

My OS is CentOS 6, the ambari-server is version 1.4.2.104, and MySQL version is Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73. I am sure MySQL server was running.

Anybody came across the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ambari DB support for MySQL was introduced in Ambari 1.4.3

http://www.slideshare.net/hortonworks/apache-ambari-whats-new-in-143

Looks like you are running Ambari 1.4.2

You can grab the latest Ambari (which happens to be Ambari 1.6.1) here:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Ambari+User+Guides